# Get min value for first date

Tags: minimum

everyone.

I'm busy creating a reporting view in SQL, but I'm struggling a bit with some logic I need. I have:

- SubscriberID
- MSISDN
- ICCID
- VOUCHERCODE
- RECHARGEDATE

I need to find the first date a voucher was bought, as well as the value of that voucher. The SubscriberID, MSISDN and ICCID fields form a 'unique key'.

I'm just struggling to figure out how to display first date and first voucher. There are several vouchers for instance on the first date. I'm completely lost.

I've got:

```
> select subscriberid, MSISDN, ICCID, 'first'(VoucherCode),
> 'first'(RECHARGEDATE) from table
```

That returns more than one row. I need a single row. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Hi there. Sorry. I'm using SQL.

Comment: I need to create a view consisting of several parts. This one is a bummer. It'll be nested CTE's.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why is your question not tagged with the SQL dialect you want to use? Can you share sample data and the expected output corresponding to that data?

Answer (score -1):

It turns out I wasn't using to_date() on the recharge date. It's working now.

Comment: What does that mean?